# How to send value with URL in ejs template

Tags: javascript, html, mean-stack, ejs

I want to send a value with the help of which i get from my database

```
<% pp.forEach(function(a){ %>
   <h1><a href="/users/gotospecific/{a.title}"><%= a.title %></a></h1>
```

but due to some problem error occured.

can someone guide me about the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Shouldn't you concatenate your {a.title} in the href ? something like href="/users/gotospecific/"+{a.title}+"" ?

Comment: @PierreBurton,   can i use ? href="/users/gotospecific?topic = "{a.title}+""

Comment: I don't know which method you use for your routing. All I did was to point that I believe there's a mistake in your template code.

Comment: app.get('/gotospecific',function(){ var topic = req.query.topic; });

Comment: I want to use key topic as a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the following on your server:

```
app.get('/gotospecific', function(req, res) {
    var topic = req.query.topic;
    ...
})
```

then you'll need this in EJS:

```
<% pp.forEach(function(a) { %>
    <h1><a href="/users/gotospecific?topic=<%= a.title %>"><%= a.title %></a></h1>
<% }); %>
```

where `pp` is assumed to be an array of objects that have `title` properties. e.g.

```
res.render('myview', {pp: [{title: 'First item'}]});
```

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax for ejs is :

```
<% pp.forEach(function(a){ %>
  <h1><a href="/users/gotospecific/"+<%= a.title %>+""><%= a.title %></a></h1>
<% }); %>
```